# How to get output of the cmd?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to get output of the cmd result in a string

```
void getDevices()
{
      Process p = new Process();
      ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
      proc.FileName = @"C:\Users\mehmetcan\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe";
      proc.Arguments = @"devices";
      Process.Start(proc);
      String output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();           
}
```

> *Error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll*

Comment: On which exact line? Did you debug your code?

Comment: Yes. When I execute that, it returns "0123456 device". I want to show it in a label

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to give your process a ProcessStartInfo that tells it you're going to be reading the output.

Here is an example:

```
ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startinfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\mehmetcan\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe";
startinfo.Arguments = @"devices";
startinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startinfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

// Note: declare process as a variable in the class as it needs to be used in the event handlers
process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = startinfo;

process.OutputDataReceived += process_DataReceived;
process.ErrorDataReceived += process_DataReceived;
process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

And then the event hander that receives the data (this is called each time the process outputs something):

```
private void process_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    // null data means we've received everything
    if (e.Data == null) {
        process.CancelOutputRead();
        process.CancelErrorRead();
        return;
    }

    // e.Data is the string with the output from the process
    Console.Write(e.Data);
}
```

Note that `process_DataReceived` is called whenever the process outputs something, if what you need is to get the complete output, then you can do this:

```
process_output = ""; // reset output before starting the process

ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startinfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\mehmetcan\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe";
startinfo.Arguments = @"devices";
startinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startinfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = startinfo;

process.OutputDataReceived += process_DataReceived;
process.ErrorDataReceived += process_DataReceived;
process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();

// check end of answer if you need to wait for the process to terminate
```

Declare a string variable that is available to both `process_DataReceived` and to `process_Exited`, for example a variable in the class that contains the methods:

```
string process_output; // will accumulate the output of the process
```

And then the event handlers:

```
private void process_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    // null data means we've received everything
    if (e.Data == null) {
        process.CancelOutputRead();
        process.CancelErrorRead();

        // do something with the output:
        Console.Write(process_output);

        return;
    }

    // append the output to the accumulator
    process_output += e.Data;
}
```

After the process exits, you can still receive output data, therefore if you need to wait for the process to finish, you can add a flag (a boolean) and set it to false only when you receive null data in `process_DataReceived`. You can only be sure you've received all of the output from the process when that happens.

#### Access UI From 'process_DataReceived'

If you have to access a UI element from `process_DataReceived` you can do so by using it's dispatcher.
Here is an example:

```
private void process_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    // null data means we've received everything
    if (e.Data == null) {
        process.CancelOutputRead();
        process.CancelErrorRead();

        // with WPF:
        mylabel.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
            mylabel.Content = process_output;
        }));

        // with WinForms
        mylabel.Invoke((MethodInvoker) (() =>
        {
            mylabel.Text = process_output;
        }));

        return;
    }

    // append the output to the accumulator
    process_output += e.Data;
}
```

Comment: There are some issues in the above code, 1, you should be sure to close StandardInput. And 2, the IO events can fire after the process has exited, so you need to handle that. http://csharptest.net/321/how-to-use-systemdiagnosticsprocess-correctly/

Comment: @josh poley: Ah, so that's why we can receive null data. Thanks for the info! Editing right away.

Comment: @100GPing100 thanks for your help.
It works well.it Displays the output on console. However I want to display it in label.
Here is code : `label1.Text = process_output;` but it gives error again it says : _label1 is using by another work piece_ can you help me again?

Comment: @user2922744: Added information on how to do that. I think it is working code for both WPF and WinForms (haven't used WinForms in a while).

Comment: `private void process_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            // null data means we've received everything
            if (e.Data == null)
            {
                process.CancelOutputRead();
                process.CancelErrorRead();

                // do something with the output:

                
                Console.Write(process_output);
                //label1.Text = process_output;
               

                return;
            }

           process_output += e.Data;
        }` @100GPing100 what should I do?

Comment: I added it to the answer, something like: `label1.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { label1.Text = process_output; }));`

Comment: Sorry I make you busy.
_'System.Windows.Forms.Label' does not contain a definition for 'Dispatcher' and no extension method 'Dispatcher' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Label' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)_
I have include Windows Base and System.Windows.Threading;

Comment: As I feared, the solution I posted is only valid for WPF. Adding a solution for WinForms.

Comment: I want to send you a gift :D
thank you for your cooperation
@100GPing100

Comment: @user2922744: it was my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

How about trying like this:-

```
public static void Main()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
        proc.FileName = @"C:\Users\mehmetcan\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe";
         proc.Arguments = @"devices";

        Process p = Process.Start(proc);
        p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
        p.BeginOutputReadLine();
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
```

Also check **[Process.OutputDataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx)** and **[Process.BeginOutputReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline.aspx)**

Comment: Thanks for help.
However, Im beginner for c# and dotnet. Same error for your code also

  for this line: `p.BeginOutputReadLine();`